# How to create a sharepoint site collection remotely via powershell?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

How to create a new site collection remotely via Powershell
I have tried the following and all failed
Trial one:

```
# Create a PSCredential Object using the "User" and "Password" parameters that you passed to the job
$SecurePassword = '...............' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "domain\user", $SecurePassword
$spms = New-PSSession -ComputerName servername -Credential $cred 


$Parameters= @{

Session = $spms

ArgumentList ="siteurl","sitename",'domain\user','domain\user2'
ScriptBlock = { Param ($SiteURL,$SiteName,$SiteOwner,$SecondSiteOwner)
                Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                Function Recreate_Site_Collection ($SiteURL,$SiteName,$SiteTemplate,$SiteOwner,$SecondSiteOwner){
# Delete Site Collection
$site = get-spsite  -Identity $SiteURL -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if($site){

Write-host "Removing the site $SiteURL" -f Red
Remove-SPSite -Identity $SiteURL -Confirm:$false
}
# Create Site Collection
Write-host "creating  the site $SiteURL" -f green
echo $SiteOwner 
echo $SecondSiteOwner
New-SPSite -Name $SiteName -Url $SiteURL -Template $SiteTemplate -OwnerAlias $SiteOwner -SecondaryOwnerAlias $SecondSiteOwner -Confirm:$false
}
                $SiteTemplate = "DEV#0" #Developer Site Template

                 Recreate_Site_Collection $SiteURL $SiteName $SiteTemplate $SiteOwner $SecondSiteOwner
}}
Invoke-Command  @Parameters
```

Error:
The user cannot be found.
however, if I run the same code on the server with the same variables it goes ok when I run the PowerShell as an admin

Trial two:

```
# Create a PSCredential Object using the "User" and "Password" parameters that you passed to the job
$SecurePassword = '..........' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "domain/user", $SecurePassword
$spms = New-PSSession -ComputerName servername -Credential $cred 


$Parameters= @{
Session = $spms
ArgumentList = "siteurl","sitename",'domain/user',"1033","DEV#0"
ScriptBlock = { Param ($PortalUrl,$SiteName,$userName,$LCID,$WebTemplate)
$adminSiteUrl = "centraladminurl"
$user = "user"
$pwd = '..............'
$securePwd = ConvertTo-SecureString $pwd -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object PSCredential($user, $securePwd)
$wsdlUrl = $adminSiteUrl + "/_vti_adm/Admin.asmx?WSDL"
$svc = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $wsdlUrl -Credential $cred
$svc.Timeout = 300000    # 5 minute timeout
$svc.CreateSite(
    $siteUrl,   # URL
    $siteTitle, # Title
    $Description, # Description
    $LCID, # LCID 1033 arabic
    $WebTemplate,    # WebTemplate
    $user,      # Owner Login
    "user",  # Owner Name
    "mail",
    $PortalUrl ,
    "portalname"
    )}}
    
    Invoke-Command  @Parameters
```

Error:
Exception calling "CreateSite" with "10" argument(s): "Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown."
however, also when running the same script on the server itself with PowerShell run as admin it works with the same variables

please help
I need to automate SharePoint deployment from Jenkins which require a remotely PowerShell script and the main step is creating the site it cannot be established

Comment: This similar answer may help, it looks like you can run into issues with claims auth: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/108504/new-spsite-could-not-find-user-when-using-saml-claims . What is the value of `$user` before you run `CreateSite()`?

Comment: actually, it's not the same in this solution he is using ADFS but I am using the domain "windows user" and it works normally on the local machine as I run the PowerShell as admin  and I have tried it but I cannot create the claim as I cannot Create the trusted login provider

Comment: please help as all deployment cannot be automated from anywhere "TFS, Jenkins" as I cannot recreate the SharePoint site remotely if there is any solution rather than TFS, Jenkins with PowerShell you are welcome only I need to recreate SharePoint site collection remotely

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely a permissions issue, but it can be kind of a pain to find. My user (the one running the script - probably your Jenkins user) was:

- a local admin on the server,
- listed in `https://sharepointsite/` > Site Settings > Permissions > Site Collection Administrators.

but still got weird errors when running remotely:

```sh
# These commands did not work - I'm quoting the errors:
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName MySPServer
Add-PSSnapIn Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
$URI = 'https://MySharePoint.domain.com'

# Can't pipe Site object to Web
Get-SPSite $URI | Get-SPWeb
'Get-SPWeb : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))'

# Can't get SP users using web:
$web = Get-SPWeb $URI
Get-SPUser 'DOMAIN\user' -Web $web
'Get-SPUser : Cannot find an SPWeb object with Id or Url: 7aee0dc1-fe3b-4f9b-bd4b-000000000000 and Site Id: 8b662499-bb26-41ce-978e-000000000000.'

# Can't list properties of a site object
Get-SPSite $URI | fl
'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'

# Can't create a new site because the user can't be found:
New-SPSite -Url $URI -Name 'Test' -Description 'Test Site' -Template 'DEV#0' -OwnerAlias 'DOMAIN\user'
'New-SPSite : User cannot be found.'
```

I found that my user was not showing up as a site admin in powershell for some reason. Note that I'm running directly on the server here in order to view the users:

```sh
$URI = 'https://MySharePoint.domain.com'
$web = Get-SPWeb $uri
Get-SPUser "$env:USERDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME" -Web $web | Select UserLogin,IsSiteAdmin,IsSiteAuditor,AllowBrowseUserInfo

'UserLogin   IsSiteAdmin IsSiteAuditor AllowBrowseUserInfo
 ---------   ----------- ------------- -------------------
 DOMAIN\user False       False         True'
```

So I added myself as a site admin for my main site like so:

```sh
# Set my user as collection admin:
Get-SPUser 'DOMAIN\User' -Web $web | Set-SPUser -IsSiteCollectionAdmin:$true

# Check permissions again:
Get-SPUser "$env:USERDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME" -Web $web | Select UserLogin,IsSiteAdmin,IsSiteAuditor,AllowBrowseUserInfo

'UserLogin   IsSiteAdmin IsSiteAuditor AllowBrowseUserInfo
 ---------   ----------- ------------- -------------------
 DOMAIN\user True        True          True'

Get-SPSite $uri | fl UserIsSiteAdminInSystem

'UserIsSiteAdminInSystem : True'
```

And now all of the above commands work normally. It seems like the powershell module for sharepoint requires some access to the main webservice object in order to resolve usernames. I'm not sure what level of access is really required, but this worked for me.